# ROS Answers SE migration: ccny-vision

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What is the importance of ccny_vision package?

when i read about it from http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny_vision , i don't understand the functionality it can do?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49780/ccny-vision/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ccny_vision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) is a stack which provides the [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) package, which is a system to track visual markers.

It was released by the CCNY Robotics lab several years ago, but unfortunately, no one is currently in charge of maintaining it here, which is why the wiki page headers (and possibly other things) are broken.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-12-05**:
thanks, i got it :)